# watir browser.attach overwrites previous browser object

Tags: watir, firewatir

I need to test login using facebook connect on my site. When clicking on connect using facebook button, a pop is open.

I use `ie = Watir::Browser.attach(:title, 'Login | Facebook')` to assign this new window to a new object. But somehow it the previous browser object also refrences the new object.

```
b = Watir::Browser.start( "http://www.pstom.com" )
b.link(:text, "Connect with Facebook").click
irb(main):081:0> puts b.title
PSToM - Home
=> nil
ie = Watir::Browser.attach(:title, 'Login | Facebook')
 puts b.title
Login | Facebook
=> nil
irb(main):085:0> puts ie.title
Login | Facebook
=> nil
```

What is going wrong (I'm testing in IRB in Ubuntu)

Comment: I tried that on my Windows machine(my Ubuntu machine has FF 4.0 so Watir doesn't work on it) and it behaved as you would expect. Have you tested this outside IRB? Also, is there any code that wasn't included in the question?

Comment: Someone with retag capability should add the firewatir tag to this question.

Comment: Also make sure you get permission from Facebook before using any automation to access their site.  Since otherwise you are in violation of the Terms of service and could suddenly find your account closed or worse yet your ip banned or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there was a problem with firewatir gem and attaching. Try the same with watir-webdriver gem (it can drive Firefox).

github: https://github.com/jarib/watir-webdriver
rubygems: https://rubygems.org/gems/watir-webdriver
installation:
https://github.com/zeljkofilipin/watirbook/blob/master/installation-ubuntu.md
https://github.com/zeljkofilipin/watirbook/downloads

Comment: Yes, this is a known bug with FireWatir, but should work fine with IE. Could the OP please confirm which they are using?

Comment: They said they were on Ubuntu, so that rules out IE I would think.

Answer (score 0):

I got the correct behavior on Windows/IE. What versions do you have? I have ruby 1.8.7 and watir 1.7.1

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'watir'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> a = Watir::Browser.attach(:title, 'Google')
=> #<Watir::IE:0x4ecfde0 url="http://www.google.com/" title="Google">
irb(main):003:0> puts a.title
Google
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> b = Watir::Browser.attach(:title, 'Bing')
=> #<Watir::IE:0x4ea59d8 url="http://www.bing.com/" title="Bing">
irb(main):005:0> puts b.title
Bing
=> nil
irb(main):006:0> puts a.title
Google
=> nil
irb(main):007:0>
```